# Strange reputation change of -1 then +1 after downvoting answer and upvoting a comment on the answer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

For the question [Is there a shorthand version of a selector's "or" for the same element type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11747634/is-there-a-shorthand-version-of-a-selectors-or-for-the-same-element-type/11747731#11747731) I (1) downvoted (my first downvote!) an incorrect answer and (2) upvoted a comment on that answer that indicated it was incorrect. Then the author of the incorrect answer commented "oops" and deleted the answer.

As far as I can see, there should have been no change to my reputation -- but I got a -1 reputation for a downvote and then a +1 reputation for the deletion. No big deal, but I  thought I better report the bug here. (Unless of course I'm missing something and this is supposed to happen?)

Comment: You got -1 rep for downvoting an answer. You got your rep. point back when the downvoted answer was deleted. Everything works as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Things are working as expected.

You lost 1 reputation point due to downvoting an answer.

When the answer was deleted, the 1 reputation point was "recovered" from it.

This is the system working as it is supposed to.

See [How does "Reputation" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)